# How to create a datetime column with default value in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

Is there a way to create a table in sqlite3 that has a datetime column that defaults to 'now'?

The following statement returns a syntax error:

```
create table tbl1(id int primary key, dt datetime default datetime('now'));
```

**Update**: Here's the correct ddl courtesy of [Sky Sanders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242897/sky-sanders):

```
create table tbl1(id int primary key, dt datetime default current_timestamp);
```

Comment: @NobodyMan - perhaps you could update your question and include the ddl that works for others to easily find.

Comment: @Sky - I'm not opposed, but doesn't that make your answer redundant?  Also, if I do edit  should I replace the incorrect snippet  or simply append to the question with the correct answer?   I'm a bit ignorant of SO etiquette :-)

Comment: It doesn't really diminish an answer when you ADD an update to your question with an example of what ultimately worked for you. A lot of answers can be helpful suggestions, as mine was with the ddl fragment and background, which helped you fix your ddl. Confirming the solution by adding the correct statement is a value add. Under no circumstances change the original code, that is how someone with the same problem will find this solution. Anyway, is a moot point, I  edited my answer to present a working version of your ddl.  cheers

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table tbl1(id int primary key, dt datetime default current_timestamp);
```

Background:

> The DEFAULT constraint specifies a
>   default value to use when doing an
>   INSERT. The value may be NULL, a
>   string constant, a number, or a
>   constant expression enclosed in
>   parentheses. The default value may
>   also be one of the special
>   case-independant keywords
>   CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_DATE or
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. If the value is
>   NULL, a string constant or number, it
>   is inserted into the column whenever
>   an INSERT statement that does not
>   specify a value for the column is
>   executed. If the value is
>   CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_DATE or
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, then the current
>   UTC date and/or time is inserted into
>   the columns. For CURRENT_TIME, the
>   format is HH:MM:SS. For CURRENT_DATE,
>   YYYY-MM-DD. The format for
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is "YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS".

From http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: Note that `current_timestamp` is precise to the second, if you want milliseconds use `default (STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'NOW'))`.

Answer (score 18):

```
... default (datetime(current_timestamp))
```

The expression following `default` must be in parentheses. This form is useful if you want to perform date arithmetic using [SQLite date and time functions or modifiers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: Doug, parenth are only required if an expression is involved. The 'current_xxxx' are keywords and act as literal-value. http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint

Comment: Sky, yes, isn't that what I said? My point is that if you want more than what the keywords provide, you may use expressions, but the expression must be in parentheses; the create statement in the original question was missing the parentheses.

Comment: There's no reason to write datetime(current_timestamp). Just use current_timestamp.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I should have used a more complicated example, such as default (datetime('now','start of day'))

Comment: `DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime'))` is useful if you want the local time.

Answer (score 8):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a literal-value just like `'mystring'`

**column-constraint:**

[image]

**literal-value:**

[image]

Comment: Yes, and the `datetime('now')` the OP used is an `expr`, so it needs the parentheses.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the following query for using current date value in your table

```
create table tablename (date_field_name Created_on default CURRENT_DATE);
```

Comment: off topic, original question is about a datetime field, not a date field.