# SQL Insert combine a value and columns from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to create a row in an existing table which consists of current timestamp, and some other data from other table.

What would be a correct syntax to achieve it? Below is a pseudo code for what I am trying to achieve.

```
INSERT INTO logTable
    VALUES( currentTimeStamp, select data1, data2, data3 FROM datatable WHERE data1 = 123);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot mix `insert . . . values` and `insert . . . select`.  Just use:

```
INSERT INTO logTable
    select currentTimeStamp, data1, data2, data3
    FROM datatable
    WHERE data1 = 123;
```

Or, better yet, set up the column to have a default value of the current time stamp so it gets set automatically.

Comment: can I set up the column to have a default timestamp in SQLite3?

Comment: The simple answer is "yes" . . . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614483/can-i-create-a-datetime-column-with-default-value-in-sqlite3.

Comment: Thanks Gordon and Eez. I got it working as required thanks to your answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO logTable (column1, column2, column3,column4)
  select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,data1, data2, data3 FROM datatable WHERE data1 = 123
```

You can use something else instead of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, but make sure column types matches.