# How to get the sum of different table but the same column names

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have 2 questions but they are almost related.

**1st question:**

I have 4 different tables named **breakfast,lunch,dinner and others** but they have the same column names like **Fat,Calories and Iron.**

What is the best possible way to add them and show them on a Textview as one for each **(Fat,Calories and Iron)**

Like for example

```
Total Fat is (111)
Total Calories is (222)
Total Iron is (333)
```

**2nd question**

How about if i want to all display data of columns of different tables.
How can i display all the values of column fat from different tables in sqlite?

**For example, I have this on my sqlite database**

```
breakfast table    lunch table        dinner table       others table 
  Fat column       Fat column          Fat column         Fat column
   1                  3                    6                  9
   2                  4                    7                  10
   3                  5                    8                  11
```

and  I want to show that on textview something like this

```
Fats
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

Comment: *I have 2 questions* - so you should ask two separate questions

Comment: Maybe I should ask different questions sir, But this 2 question arent far enough from each other, so I think that a peson could answer one of these question can also answer the other one.

Answer (score 2):

I would make 1 table and add a column called timeOfDay

in the database helper handler class

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getFats(int timeOfDay) {
    //0:breakfast
    //1:lunch
    //3:dinner
    //4:other
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE timeOfDay = " + timeOfDay;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        result.add(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("fatColumn")));
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            result.add(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("fatColumn")));
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```

Inside the activity you want to display information

```
ArrayList<Integer> fats = db.getFats(1);
int fatTotal = 0;
for(Integer fat : fats){
    //output string for this particular fat reading
    fatTotal += fat;
}
//output string of sum sort for totalFat
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have 4 different tables named breakfast,lunch,dinner and others but they have the same column names like Fat,Calories and Iron

Having different tables with the same columns should be your primary problem, not how to combine separate tables. (Because `JOIN`'s and cross-table scans are expensive)

You should rather do this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS meals (
  _id PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  meal_time VARCHAR(20), 
  fat INTEGER, 
  calories INTEGER, 
  iron INTEGER,
  time_eaten DEFAULT current_timestamp
)
```

Ref on default values - [Can I create a datetime column with default value in sqlite3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614483/can-i-create-a-datetime-column-with-default-value-in-sqlite3)

Then you'd `INSERT` a value with `meal_time = 'dinner'` and select `WHERE meal_time = 'dinner'`, for example.

At that point, your second question is trivial...

```
SELECT fat from meals ORDER BY meal_time;
```

If you want the specific options of dinner, lunch, breakfast, then add a `WHERE` as shown.